# Android Studio: Unable to generate google cloud endpoint for JDO annotated Entity class

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, maven-gae-plugin

In android studio, I am experimenting with the GAE cloud endpoint and able to generate endpoints from JPA annotated entity classes. But if I define the entity class with JDO annotation, the option of generating endpoint is disabled (**Tool-> Google Cloud Endpoints -> generate Endpoint**). 

How do I add the support for generating Endpoint for JDO Annotated Entity class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created the [issue 58410](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58410), and there is the following reply:

> "Sorry, we don't have JDO support yet.  We're concentrating on JPA.  It is disabled because it doesn't appear to be a "valid" JPA annotated Entity.
>
> There is no timeline yet for JDO support."